# Scalar multiplication on tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

I am in the process of getting comfortable with tensor products (it's going very slowly). My question needs the following setup:

> We have a finite $K$-algebra $A$ and $L\supset K$ fields. We constucted the the product: $A\otimes_KL$.

I was recently told that for $\sum x_i\otimes y_j\in A\otimes_KL$ and $\lambda\in L$ we have:$$\lambda\sum x_i\otimes y_j\overset{\text{(simply)}}{=}\sum x_i\otimes(\lambda y_j).$$

Now I don't quite see how I should see this. For as far as I know, the tensor product is defined to be linear over $K$. So if we would have had $\lambda\in K$, I would be convinced. However I don't see why a $\lambda \in L$ is suddenly allowed to be treated the way it is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A priori, $A \otimes_K L$ does not have an $L$-module structure. However, the equation you have above defines an $L$-module structure on it. In other words, this is a definition, not a proposition.

Answer (score 1):

You can either think of a $K$-multilinear map, or equivalently use the free vector space definition. In the latter case $\lambda\sum x_i\otimes y_j-\sum x_i\otimes\lambda y_j$ is in the ideal to be quotiented away.